# Compile AMT (Automatic Multicast Tunneling) on Linux

Tags: c, makefile, multicast

There is an old [project](http://cs.utdallas.edu) about Automatic Multicast Tunneling (AMT). I am trying to compile it on Ubuntu 11.10, but i get an error.

1. cd amt
2. ./configure
3. make

Error:

```
Making all in test_patricia
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/amt/test_patricia'
-I../libmem -I../libpatricia -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -c `test -f 'test-patricia.c' || echo './'`test-patricia.c
test-patricia.c: In function ‘pat2my’:
test-patricia.c:53:23: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

make[1]: *** [test-patricia.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/amt/test_patricia'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Codeline:

```
    static inline mynode *
    pat2my (patext *ext)
    {
        return((mynode *)((int) ext - offsetof(mynode, extkey)));
    }
```

Any solutions? How to remove the error in the code or how to remove the Werror option in make.

Comment: Change `(int)` to `(void *)` I think

Comment: Seems like you are compiling code which was written for a 32 bit system on a 64 bit machine. That is why sizeof(int) and sizeof(void*) is different, and thus the error. So maybe you can try (long)ext instead of (int)ext.

Comment: I removed the werror flag in the makefiles, but in the end, there is too less documentation, i don't know how to test it...